# Tables do not have a uid

Tags: sql, sequelize.js

I have a script to generate tables in my data base, when I run the script some table are generated with associated users , but some don't.
after running the script I execute the query comes below, the some does not have the uid associated

```
SELECT * FROM sysobjects t
left JOIN sysusers u
ON u.uid = t.uid
order by t.name
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.extended_properties td
ON td.major_id = t.id AND td.minor_id = 0 AND td.name = 'MS_Description'
WHERE t.type = 'u';
```

[image]

This query is made by sequelize to generate models out of database tables

Comment: Your query is not standard SQL.  I am surprised it runs at all.

Comment: @GordonLinoff what is wrong with this query ? if I may ask

Comment: can you show the tables shortly?

Comment: @sishanov . . . `order by` does not fit in the middle of a query.